# Use if/else statement without else branch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, database-trigger

I don't know how to use if else in this case. When score > 10, stop insert. Else continue insert as normally. But what is the syntax to do that?

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER invalidScore ON dbo.dbo_score
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @score DECIMAL;
SET @score = (SELECT s.score FROM Inserted s);
IF(@score > 10)
BEGIN
  RETURN 'score must be less than 10'
  ROLLBACK TRAN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things you need to change for this trigger to work:

1. Remove the `else` section - its optional.
2. Handle the fact that `Inserted` may have multiple rows.
3. `Throw` the error rather than using the `return` statement so you can handle it in the client. And throw it after rolling back the transaction in progress.

Corrected trigger follows:

```
create trigger invalidScore on dbo.dbo_score
after insert
as
begin
  if exists (select 1 from Inserted S where S.Score > 10) begin
    rollback tran;
    throw 51000, 'score must be less than 10', 1;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, creating these types of `sql` objects should use `begin.. end` blocks. Second is,you can ignore the `else` statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER invalidScore ON dbo.dbo_score
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @score DECIMAL;
    SET @score = (SELECT s.score FROM Inserted s);
    IF(@score > 10)
        BEGIN
            RETURN 'score must be less than 10'
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

'Else' is an option section you can remove this and use it,but i may like you to consider using check constraints for scenarios like this rather than adding a trigger check on score column

e.g.
CREATE TABLE dbo.dbo_score(

```
Score int CHECK (score < 10)
```

);

A CHECK constraint is faster, simpler, more portable, needs less code and is less error prone